# How to Identify Particular(specific) view is clicked for Dynamically Created Views

Tags: android

I am new to android programming.
I have created some Buttons,EditText dynamically and set onclick listener for all of them.
here for some buttons and EditText i have to write different logic.

if i write

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

 if(v instanceof Button){     
// do some thing

 }else if(v instanceof EditText){

// do some thing
}
  }
```

for all the buttons and EditText same logic is applied.
But i want for some specific logic for some buttons and Edittext.
I can do this by setting tag for some Editext/Buttons and Identify.
Is this the Only Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    in onClick you can write switch case based on id of each component (button etc):

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){

                case R.id.camera:
                      break;

                case R.id.camera_focused:
                      break;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have created Buttons and EditText Dynamically, How do i write case R.id.Button1 ?

Comment: You can add for each of your buttons and use them.. do it like this : button.getId(). but try using xml. your code will be more flexible

Comment: or where you write the listener, there only handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click to change second line of text");
        OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean clicked = false;
        int numClicks = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(numClicks > 5)
            {
                button.setText("STOP IT");
            }
            numClicks++;
            if(clicked == false){
                clicked = true;
                tv2.setText("Text Changed on Button Click");    
            }
            else
            {
                clicked = false;
                tv2.setText("Click again");
            }

            }
        };
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
```